# meaning of "come by"

Tags: meaning

I am grateful if you could clarify the meaning of the following message I got from my supervisor in college.

"Please come by this coming Tuesday for an chat."

Which do you think is correct?
(1) come by = drop by
(2) come by = come before

Comment: Well, you’re a very good student to pick up the ambiguity.  Which do YOU think?

Comment: really difficult..., but I am just thinking (1) might be correct

Comment: I think so too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**come by**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+by) idiom

> 2. Stop in, visit, as in:

"Please come by this coming Tuesday for a chat."